# Help on Cases batch class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, governorlimits

I have created the batch class which will store the count in other object with status "New" and "Closed"
I have 60 Case records with 25 as "New" status and remaining with "Closed" status

when i am running batch of 25 then my count is coming 0 for "New".

because in 3rd batch there is no record with "New" status Values.Please suggest how to tackle this.

```
global class CaseBatchApex implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
global List<string>lstcount;
global List<integer>lstcount1;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT ID, status FROM case');
}
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<case> scope){

        integer count2;
       Map<case,string> casemap=new Map<case,string>();
      Map<case,string> casemap1=new Map<case,string>();
        System.debug('Scope>>>'+scope);
        for(case c:scope){
            if(c.status=='New'){
            casemap.put(c,c.Status);
            }
            else if(c.status=='Closed'){
            casemap1.put(c,c.Status);
            }
        }
       lstcount=new list<string>([select count() from case where status in:casemap.values()]);
        lstcount1=new list<integer>([select count() from case where status in:casemap1.values()]);
          CaseCount cse=new CaseCount();
        cse.id='a077F000001pAxb';
        cse.New_Status_count__c=string.valueof(lstcount.size());
        cse.Closed_Status_Count__c=string.valueof(lstcount1.size());
        update cse;  
}    

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you are updating your `CaseCount` object record in every batch run, so if the 25 `Case` records with `New` status are in the previous batch run, you will overwrite the count in the third run to 0.

Try this:

```
global class CaseBatchApex implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Status FROM Case');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Case> cases){
        CaseCount caseCount = [SELECT Id, New_Status_count__c, Closed_Status_Count__c 
                               FROM CaseCount 
                               WHERE Id = 'a077F000001pAxb'];

        for(Case c : cases){
            if(c.status == 'New') {
                caseCount.New_Status_count__c = cse.New_Status_count__c + 1;
            } else if (c.status == 'Closed') {
                caseCount.Closed_Status_Count__c = cse.Closed_Status_Count__c + 1;
            }
        }

        update caseCount;  
    }    

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){} 
}
```